# Sprint batch update insert on heavy db takes time

Tags: spring-batch

I have implemented a spring batch, which reads data from csv files and insert and update based on records

I have a table XXX037 which has 800k records and it takes too much time inserting and updating it.

I have used spring batch configuration, commit-interval of 1000. Still it takes time to process

Is there any way i can improve performance?

Configiraion

```
<batch:job id="pcqJob">
        <batch:step id="pcqStep">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="pcqReader" writer="compositeWriter" commit-interval="1000">
                 <!-- <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="javax.persistence.PersistenceException"/>                
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>  -->
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
<!-- <bean id="skipPolicy" class="com.test.domain.services.writer.SkipPolicy">
<property name="skipLimit" value="2500"/>
</bean> -->


    <bean id="compositeWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter">
        <property name="classifier">
            <bean class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
                <property name="routerDelegate">
                    <bean class="com.test.domain.services.writer.ItemCodeClassifier" />
                </property>
                <property name="matcherMap">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="*Doss*" value-ref="fileItemWriter1" />
                        <entry key="*Ldt*" value-ref="fileItemWriter2" />
                        <entry key="*Old*" value-ref="oldDossierfileItemWriter" />
                        <entry key="*Tpm*" value-ref="tpmfileItemWriter" />
                        <entry key="*Txm*" value-ref="tpxfileItemWriter" />
                        <entry key="*DoD*" value-ref="dossierDeletefileItemWriter" />
                        <entry key="*LdD*" value-ref="ldtDeletefileItemWriter" />
                        <entry key="*TpD*" value-ref="tpmDeletefileItemWriter" />
                        <entry key="*TxD*" value-ref="txmDeletefileItemWriter" />
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Have you applied partition?

Comment: NO i am using jdbctemplate.update inside for loop , but now changed it to outside for loop and do it by jdbctemplate.batchupdate

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your job to see what could go wrong?

Comment: You can use Partition to see if the batch can finish 800k faster

Comment: Is there any example ? it would help